# Visual Studio 2010 constantly crashing when opening a new project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crash, logging

My [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) installation (version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel) is crashing when I open a C# project. After the crash, it reopens in a new window, but all the text is black, intellisense doesn't work, etc.

I reinstalled it, installed fixes, etc., but nothing is helping.

The last activity log entry before the crash is:

```
<entry>
    <record>262</record>
    <time>2012/01/22 12:04:12.473</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]</description>
    <guid>{E269B994-EF71-4CE0-8BCD-581C217372E8}</guid>
  </entry>
```

How do I isolate the error?

Comment: Do you have any extensions loaded?

Comment: Not that I would know of, no. It's a clean install without any extensions. Installed two days ago and it still does that.

Comment: Also, the OS (Win 7 64bit) is freshly installed. EDIT: On my other partition with the same OS it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying reference assemblies, from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies to wherever your *Program Files* is, solved the problem. Apparently Visual Studio can't handle this if you don't have your PF in the standard folder. Problem solved.

Comment: What is the final folder structure then? A lot of files in folder "C:\Program Files"? Or a folder named "Reference Assemblies" inside folder "C:\Program Files"?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me with this (or very similar) issue in VS 2013 Update 4.
http://blogs.msmvps.com/kenlin/2014/07/31/hello-world/

Basically remove `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache`